# FLUTTER: Conocer el estado actual del GPS en una App ON/OFF

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Necesito saber el estado actual del GPS en la app, estoy haciendo una app con google maps y necesito indicarle al usuario que encienda el gps al entrar a la app y en caso de que la app este abierta y el gps se cierre por alguna razon(el usuario lo haga) la app capte ese estado también

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar plugin `geolocator` , aquí tienes el link.

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Ya con eso puedes validar el estado del GPS de la siguiente forma:

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Geolocator geolocator = 
Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager = true;
GeolocationStatus geolocationStatus  = await 
geolocator.checkGeolocationPermissionStatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Buscando en el foro de StackOverFlow, encontré que con las dependencias del [geolocations](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocation) puedes revisar si el servicio está operacional y con ello personalizar el comportamiento.

```
final GeolocationResult result = await Geolocation.isLocationOperational();
if(result.isSuccessful) { 
    // El servicio está activo 
} else { 
    // El servicio estáa inactivo, restringido o los permisos han sido denegados. 
}
```

Te adjunto [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097428/is-gps-activated-flutter) a la pregunta y respuesta original. Saludos.